# Why is a meta-universally quantified variable renamed and how is it prevented?

Tags: rename, isabelle

Consider the following silly example

```
theory meta_all
imports Main
begin

lemma strict_subset: "⟦ A ⊂ B ⟧ ⟹ ∃a ∈ B. a ∉ A"
apply(blast)
done

lemma strict_subset2: "∀A B. A ⊂ B ⟶ (∃a ∈ B. a ∉ A)"
apply(blast)
done

lemma "¬ (∃A. A ⊂ A)"
apply(rule notI)
apply(erule exE)
```

Next I would like to use the `strict_subset` lemma and substitute `A` for both `A` and `B`, and it will do that, but it will rename the existing `A` to `Aa`, totally defeating the purpose of introducing the lemma.

```
apply(insert strict_subset [where A="A" and B="A"])
```

If I use the derived lemma `strict_subset2` everything works out fine, so I'm confident my reasoning is sound.

```
apply(insert strict_subset2)
apply(erule_tac x="A" in allE, erule_tac x="A" in allE)
apply(drule mp, assumption)
apply(erule bexE, erule notE, assumption)
done

end
```

The point is that most standard lemmas are of the form `strict_subset` and not of the form `strict_subset2` and the makers of Isabelle can not have intended me to make my own `strict_subset2` myself first, so ergo, I must be doing something wrong.

I would like to understand why `A` is renamed? I think it has something to do with the typing system, as I think I've also seen examples where meta-universal quantification was not a problem as long as the type was exactly right.

The other question is if I can prevent the renaming of `A` somehow?

Of course it is very well possible that both questions actually become irrelevant with the really right answer as I'm still quite fresh to Isabelle.

PS. Is it possible to get the nice symbols from Isabelle here too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a narrow technical answer, without embarking on the question if this path of experimentation makes any sense.

In your situation of

```
apply(insert strict_subset [where A="A" and B="A"])
```

the subgoal in question was this:

```
⋀A. A ⊂ A ⟹ False
```

but the locally bound (green) `A` is a so-called "parameter" of the subgoal, which means it is hidden inside the goal context.  The use of `strict_subset [where A="A" and B="A"]` refers to the context of the *proof text*, not the *proof goal*.  So you get different (free, undeclared) `A`, which is also indicated by special highlighting in the prover output.

There is a special set of (very old-fashioned) tactics that allow to dive under the implicit goal context and do some instantiation.  Here is an example:

```
apply(cut_tac A = A and B = A in strict_subset)
```

Now you have the instance for the green `A` inside the goal state, but that also got split into too subgoals due to the form of your rule, and the way this odd `cut_tac` works.

Note that there are basically the following catgories of Isabelle/Isar proof methods:

- structured Isar proof steps: notably `rule`
- weakly structured steps with indication of reasoning direction: `erule`, `drule`, `frule`
- old-style tactic emulations that allow to enter the implicit goal context with its parameters: `rule_tac`, `erule_tac`, `drule_tac`, `frule_tac`

PS: You can copy-paste unicode output from Isabelle/jEdit into this text editor.

Comment: The difference between _proof text_ and _proof goal_ doesn't want to sink in yet, but thanks for giving me right direction to chew on it a bit more. For now the `cut_tac` will allow me finish my exercise. It is becoming increasingly clear I have to look into structured Isar proofs and not try everything with proof scripts. Thanks again.

Comment: You will definitely learn something there.  Just don't forget in the end to put `cut_tac` back on the shelf of rarely used things.

Comment: By *proof text*, Makarius means the stuff you write (`apply simp`,`apply rule`, etc.). The *proof goal* is what you see in the Output window; it's the current state of the proof. The relationship between them is: the initial *proof goal* is the lemma you stated, then you use the *proof text* to manipulate this *proof goal* until it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change `apply (insert strict_subset)` to `apply (drule strict_subset)`. Then your proof can be finished by `apply simp`.

(The `insert foo` method adds `foo` as an additional assumption, complete with the meta-quantifiers it brings with it. What you want is the `drule foo` method, which weakens one of your assumptions according to the entailment `foo`.)

Comment: Yes, in this case that works, because there is an assumption matching the major assumption of `strict_subset` and thus it subsumes my use of `drule mp` later. I'm a bit careful also with `apply simp` because `simp` will prove the whole thing from the start. I really like to understand why it is renamed, because sometimes I just don't have a matching assumption. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I see. In which case, you'll find the problem to be your use of `where`. For instance, `erule_tac x="A" in allE` works, but `erule allE[where x="A"]` would not. `where` is part of the Isar structured proof language, and unlike the old `_tac` methods, it cannot refer to the meta-variable `A`, because `A` does not appear in the *proof text*, only in the current goal state. So the `A` you get is a fresh `A`, and the other `A` and `B` variables are renamed to avoid a clash.

Comment: Ah, John is pointing in the same (right direction) in his comment already.  I leave it to him to make an Isar proof with local `fix` to avoid the problem of hidden goal parameters in the first place -- as separate answer so that people can tick that.

Answer (score 1):

Structured proofs avoid the described naming problems and also allow you to perform single-step reasoning:

```
lemma  "¬ (∃A :: 'a set. A ⊂ A)"
proof
   assume "∃A :: 'a set. A ⊂ A"
   then obtain A :: "'a set" where "A ⊂ A" ..          (* by (rule exE) *)
   then have "∃a ∈ A. a ∉ A" by (rule strict_subset)
   then obtain a where "a ∉ A" "a ∈ A" ..              (* by (rule bexE) *)
   then show False ..                                  (* by (rule notE) *)
qed
```

`..` is the same as `by rule`. You can use `using [[rule_trace]]` (and find_theorems) before a proof step to figure out which rule `rule` is using.

This structure makes it even more obvious what is happening in the proof. Of course the apply-style has definitely a more exploratory touch (which is why I often prefer it, when trying to *find* a proof), but structured proofs give you more control.